# AGP removes version from libraries build.gradle: Where to put library version properly?

Tags: android, gradle, versioning, android-library

That thing haunts me for a while now:

To avoid code duplication, I moved common code parts from my main apps to custom Android Libraries. They are than added as Git submodules, included in settings.gradle and added as dependency in main apps build.gradle.

Due to [this change in 2020](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/past-releases/agp-4-1-0-release-notes#version-properties-removed-from-buildconfig-class-in-library-projects) the AGP Upgrade Assistant removes versionCode and versionName fields from the libraries build.gradle defaultConfigs.

I can not find a proper advice where to put the library version instead.
Should we use a custom README or a VERSION file? Should we add just Git tags?
There must be a best practice/ proper way to keep versioning of Android libraries without manually adding it back after every gradle upgrade, or not?

Answer (score 0):

The version number in Android is used for upgrade check. The library doesn't have this opportunity, so it's useless.

edit:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

version "1.0.0" //<<---use this

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 33

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }
    //....
}
```

Comment: I understand that it's not used by the build process anymore. But the `build.gradle` file has always ben the place for me to look up the current version of the library. So basically this question is: Whats the proper place to put the libraries version if not the build.gradle?

Comment: No, I do my versioning in git now. But there must be a better way to version Android libraries..